# How can I find out whether my GLSL compiler optimizes the following?

Tags: opengl, code-generation, glsl, shader, compiler-optimization

I'm sure GLSL compilers do a lot of optimization. I'm wondering if there is a way (maybe with a GL debug context or some extension?) to obtain the "optimized version" of a given GLSL source string *just before* it is translated into unintelligable ASM or straight GPU machine code.

Take the following example:

```
vec3 fx_Noop (const in vec3 vCol) {
    return vCol;
}
vec3 fx_Tex2D (const in vec3 vCol) {
    return fx_Noop(texture(uni_Tex2D, var_Tex2D).rgb);
}
```

Here the whole fx_Noop() definition and all calls to it should be eliminated, but more importantly fx_Tex2D() should be rewritten like this:

```
vec3 fx_Tex2D () {
    return texture(uni_Tex2D, var_Tex2D).rgb;
}
```

Since the *const in vec3 vCol* isn't being used.

Now I realize every GL driver and GLSL implementation acts differently. Still I'd like to dig into what exactly a driver does to a given GLSL source string just before assembly/compilation/linking.

I also realize the GLSL coder shouldn't write code like the above, but in a somewhat experimental code-generation scenario, things get simplified a lot when certain trade-offs can be safely made, knowing most compilers/implementations will apply a good cleansing anyway...

Comment: Optimization never happens on the source string, but on later steps, usually the abstract syntax tree, or some intermediary code.

Comment: OK guess that would *still* be interesting to be able to output/inspect...  ;)

Comment: Well, at least with MesaGL/DRI2/DRM based open source drivers you can do this. But there's no official OpenGL API to get or set the AST of the shader program. It would be a cool extension though, allowing to implement other shader programming languages than GLSL (I'd like to have shader languages like Lisp or ML).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to know for certain one way or another without profiling different shaders.